# Is the language $\{a^{n^2-1} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ context free? and how to prove it?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Is the language $\{a^{n^2-1} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ context free? and how to prove it?
I think it is, but I could not find a way to prove it by using push down automaton or any other way.

Comment: Since you were not able to prove the statement, what have you tried towards *disproving* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unary language (a subset of $a^*$) is context-free iff it is regular. This is a special case of [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem). It is not too hard to show that a unary language $L$ is regular if and only if there exist $n,m$ such that for all $N \geq n$, $a^N \in L$ iff $a^{N+m} \in L$. See if this condition holds for your language.